# I am confused That what is actually equilibrium constant. WHY THERE was a need to introduce equilibrium constant?

Tags: equilibrium

Please answer I am literally stucked into it

Comment: Why there was a need to introduce Mount Everest?

Comment: Life would be so easier without arithmetics too. No mammoths, few mammoths, many mammoths.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44894/why-is-the-equilibrium-constant-defined-that-way-intuitively?rq=1